# Adding libraries to java.library.path

Tags: java, servlets, cmd, java.library.path

I am trying to run a program which is executed by running the following batch file:

> @echo off
>
> rem Add extra JVM options here
>
> set OPTS=-Xms64m -Xmx256m
>
> rem Build command line arguments
>
> set CMD_LINE_ARGS=%1
>
> if ""%1""=="""" goto doneStart
>
> shift
>
> :setupArgs
>
> if ""%1""=="""" goto doneStart
>
> set CMD_LINE_ARGS=%CMD_LINE_ARGS% %1
>
> shift
>
> goto setupArgs
>
> :doneStart
>
> rem Launch the DCS
>
> java %OPTS% -Djava.ext.dirs=lib -Ddcs.war=war/carrot2-dcs.war org.carrot2.dcs.DcsApp
>
> %CMD_LINE_ARGS%

This batch file sets up the program at http://localhost:8080 (I believe it's a servlet). The program is a cluster engine similar to the one here: http://search.carrot2.org/stable/search. Everything seems to work, but I get the following command prompt output from executing the batch file.

> [INFO] Starting DCS...
>
> [INFO] Native LAPACK not available: no nni_lapack in java.library.path
>
> [INFO] Native BLAS not available: no nni_blas in java.library.path
>
> [INFO] DCS started on port: 8080

I managed to find the LAPACK and BLAS libraries online, but how do I add them to java.library.path (and how do I find what java.library.path points to)?

If anyone who'd like to help me needs some additional information or clarification, please let me know. I'm pretty new to java web development.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`java.library.path` is used by Java to find native libraries (dlls on Windows). You need to download LAPACK and BLAS libraries somewhere (e.g. in `C:\path\lapack\lib` and `C:\path\blas\lib`). You then need to set `java.library.path` appropriately when you call your program. For example:

```
java %OPTS% -Djava.library.path=C:\path\lapack\lib;C:\path\blas\lib -Djava.ext.dirs=lib -Ddcs.war=war/carrot2-dcs.war org.carrot2.dcs.DcsApp
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I was able to find the libraries, and they're given as java source files in an NNI package (lapack one - http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org$maven2@com.carrotsearch$nni@1.0.0@nni$LAPACK.java). Would simply pointing the path to ./nni/nni_lapack.java be acceptable? And is java.library.path basically the PATH environment variable?

Comment: You need the dlls. A quick google found them here: http://admin.hypersource.org/downloads/amer/stable/workbench/org.carrot2.util.matrix.win32.x86/os/win32/x86/.

Comment: Wow. I've been looking for dlls everywhere but was only able to find ones for C implementations and thought the java files were the way since that's all I could locate. I feel kinda stupid now. Thanks a ton for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
SET PATH=<path>/lapack.dll;<path>/blas.dll
```

Comment: The `PATH` should contain the *directory* that executables or libraries are in, not the libraries themselves.